# UnboundLocalError resolved if list is passed, why?

Tags: python

I am having a hard time understanding why Code 1 doesn't work but Code 2 does. I would really appreciate a descriptive answer.

```
Code 1:
class Solution(object):
    def Outer(self):
        def inner():
            sum += 5

        sum = 10
        inner()
        return sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Solution().Outer())

Code 2:
class Solution(object):
    def Outer(self):
        def inner():
            sum[0] += 5

        sum = [10]
        inner()
        return sum[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Solution().Outer())
```

I am sorry if it seems duplicate (as I have seen a lot of posts regarding UnboundLocalError) but I didn't find anything similar to mine, my bad.

Comment: Please provide a complete code, including instantiation of `Solution` and calling `Outer`

Comment: In #1, `inner()` is assigning a new value to `sum`, which makes it a local variable (in the absence of a `global` declaration).  But in #2, you aren't assigning to `sum`, you're just operating on its existing value, so it's not automatically local - it can still refer to the outer `sum` variable.

Comment: Actually, class is unrelevant here. You can achieve same effect with just nested functions.

Comment: You aren't *passing anything*. In the first case, you try to increment a local variable, `sum` using `+= 5`, however, sum isn't defined, hence the error. The compiler marks this as local because there is an assignment to it, that is, in Python, if you assign to a variable anywhere in a function definition it will be *local* unless you use the `global` or `nonlocal` statement. In this case, `nonlocal sum` at the top would fix this. In the second case, you *merely reference* `sum`, even though it looks like an assignment, it isn't, it mutates the object being referenced by `sum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code 1 creates a new local variable named `sum` that doesn't have an old value to add 5 to.

Code 2 doesn't create a new variable; it updates an element of the list `sum` it finds in its enclosing scope. `sum[0] += 5` doesn't assign to `sum`; it assigns to an *element* of the object referenced by the free variable `sum`.

Comment: That makes sense. How can I achieve the same in Code 1 @chepner?

Comment: @Mousumi at the beginning of `ìnner()` do `nonlocal sum` to prevent the error.

Comment: I tried with ```global sum``` at first but didn't work, though it worked with ```nonlocal sum```. What might be the reason and when to use what?